# A confusion about import in Spark

Tags: scala

I read the source code of KMeans.scala in spark and it confused me with the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.Logging  
import org.apache.spark.annotation.Experimental  
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}  
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS.{axpy, scal}  
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils  
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD  
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel  
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils  
import org.apache.spark.util.random.XORShiftRandom
```

I found the file RDD is in the path "spark-1.4.0\core\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\rdd" which corresponds to import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD. But the file MLUtils is in the path "spark-1.4.0\mllib\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\mllib\util" which corresponds to import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils.
Why their import paths start with "org.apache.spark"? It seems they are in the same folder "spark".

Answer (score 1):

> Why do their import paths start with "org.apache.spark"?

Path to the source file doesn't determine the package it belongs to, `package` declarations in it do. Nonetheless, it's standard (and useful in some ways) to put source files in the directory corresponding to the package, under `src/main/scala` or `<subproject(core and mllib in these two cases)>/src/main/scala`. Relative to it you can see the directories are `org/apache/spark/rdd` and `org/apache/spark/mllib/util`, just as in `import`s.